# Pandas :TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the the maximum wind gust for each month for the following sample of data:

```
         maxtemp    mintemp meantemp    heatdays    cooldays    rain    snow precip groundsnow  maxgustdir  maxgustspd
  time                                          
 2018-01-01 -1.3    -8.1    -4.7    22.7    0.0 0.0 1.0 0.2 17.0    26.0    54
 2018-01-02 -0.9    -7.4    -4.2    22.2    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 17.0    26.0    41
 2018-01-03 -3.0    -7.9    -5.5    23.5    0.0 0.0 0.4 0.2 17.0    27.0    70
 2018-01-04 0.0 -11.0   -5.5    23.5    0.0 2.4 7.2 8.4 11.0    12.0    96
 2018-01-05 10.0    -0.3    4.9 13.1    0.0 11.0    0.0 11.0    10.0    14.0    70
```

Here's my code:

```
w['maxgustspd'].resample('M').max()
```

As you can see i've resampled the data to monthly and am trying to get the max value for each month. Problem is there's a mix of float and string (i.e. <31) values so I get the error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Any ideas how to ignore the string dtypes?

Comment: Ignore them how? Just give a `nan`?

Comment: Are all your numbers actually stored as floats or are some of them saved as strings? You may want to actually convert the numbers to floats if its the latter.

Comment: The numbers are stored as floats in general except for the (<31) values. I'm guessing that was a threshold for recording the data? I can convert them to NaN in this case since i'm looking for the max and they obviously wouldn't qualify.

Answer (score 0):

If the <31 values are of interest, you'll want to do some clean up to remove the < and convert them to floats. If the str values are not of interest then you can convert them to NaN and .max will ignore them.

`w.maxgustspd = w.maxgustspd.map(lambda x: x if type(x) != str else np.NaN)
w['maxgustspd'].resample('M').max()`

Answer (score 0):

The spacing of your data is a little weird and you didn't post how it is being imported, so i can only hazard a guess.

Are you sure that all the columns in `maxgustspd` have data?  I have seen the issue you have described when I have a dataframe series of strings with a few gaps in them.  The gaps get filled in as NaNs, while the rest of the series stays as strings.

So, check the types of the numeric data you have imported (and convert them to float if necessary)... if the data import has weird gaps in it you might consider fixing the data issues or importing the data with `delim_whitespace=True` if the columns/rows are constantly shifting like in the posted data